`/` and `//` give different results for a multiple number
This issue is difficulting my algorithm implementation:
>>> -19.9871/2.8553
-7.0
>>> -19.9871//2.8553
-8.0

The second division should return -7.0 also. I guess this is something related to floating point errors, do you know another way to get the expected result? Using numpy.floor(-19.9871/2.8553) gives the expected result, but maybe there is a better solution...
I add some cases here based on answers:
>>> decimal.Decimal(8.5659)/decimal.Decimal(2.8553)
Decimal('2.999999999999999533405376125')
>>> np.floor(decimal.Decimal(8.5659)/decimal.Decimal(2.8553))
2
>>> round(decimal.Decimal(8.5659)/decimal.Decimal(2.8553))
3 # true value (//)

Here round does the work, but:
>>> decimal.Decimal(12.8489)/decimal.Decimal(2.8553)
Decimal('4.500017511294785017834689091')
>>> round(decimal.Decimal(12.8489)/decimal.Decimal(2.8553))
5
>>> np.floor(decimal.Decimal(12.8489)/decimal.Decimal(2.8553))
4 # true value (//)

here floor does the work.
What should I do?

That's actually a good one. I just wonder why Python doesn't show the float error...

I have no idea why the result of the first computation is displayed as 7.0, this feels like a bug (but correctly/usefully formatting floating point numbers is a hard research problem!). The actual value is closer to −7.000000000000001. I.e. strictly smaller than −7.0.

@KonradRudolph does Python not repr beyond a certain amount of decimal places?

@Bharel Most (all?) modern programming language attempt to be smart about truncating spurious floating point imprecision when formatting numbers. 99% of the time you want the value to read as 7.0 rather than 7.000…01, since the error is purely the result of limited precision rather than an actually meaningful value.

@KonradRudolph so it's not a bug, it's a precision workaround for formatting. This doesn't specify much though. According to the answer it should be as close to the binary as possible, which means it should be 7.0000...1

@KonradRudolph There's no bug, -7.0 is the result after rounding to the nearest float. This is not related to formatting.

@interjay You’re right of course. I checked whether the result was exactly −7 by multiplying both operands by 100, and the result it gave me was the above value, so I assumed that the same must hold for the original values (since ax/ay = x/y) but of course that’s no longer true for limited-precision operations.

@Bharel It would still be a QoI issue (which I’d classify as a bug in the presence of existing superior implementations). But as per interjay’s comment that’s not actually what is going on here.

float floor division internally calls the float version of divmod() floatobject.c
divmod(-19.9871, 2.8553)

Gives you (-8.0, 2.8552999999999997) hence -19.9871//2.8553 is -8.0
Whereas,
import decimal
decimal.Decimal(-19.9871)/decimal.Decimal(2.8553)

Will show you the result is:
Decimal('-7.000000000000000155531541292')

a number ever so close to -7.0 and thanks to floating point rounding "is" -7.0. See also Is floating point math broken?

Theoretically the precision should be the same, but you're saying it's because fmod is more accurate in some sense, while division operation on a double just rounds the precision error?

So divmod gives -8.0 because floating point rounding is not used (floor is expected to do the job (wrongly in this case))?

float divmod() converts it's parameters to doubles (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/75c1ca7b6c546ef674eb40bfe47f41e6045dc99b/Objects/floatobject.c#L593)
